# Proving that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2 k} } {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2 k+1}} =1. $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges and $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing and non-negative, then

\begin{equation} 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2 k} } {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2 k+1}} =1. 
\end{equation}
My attempt was to use
\begin{equation} 
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^N a_{2n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^N a_{2n} \leq 2\sum_{n=1}^N a_{2n-1}
\end{equation}
and notice that the LHS diverges as $N\rightarrow \infty$. Now
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} a_{2k-1}}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} a_{2k-1} - a_1} \geq \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k-1}}{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n+1} a_{2k-1}}=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k-1}}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k+1}}\geq \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k}}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k+1}} \geq \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k}}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2k}} = 1$$
where the decreasing- and non-negativity property of $a_n$ was used.

Finally use the divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}$.

Comment: This is clearly false. Just take $a_{2k} = 0$ and $a_{2k+1} = 1$ for all $k$. Then $$\begin{equation} 
\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2 k} } {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_{2 k+1}} =0
\end{equation}$$ for all $n$.

Comment: Did you mean to say if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is **convergent** (and the denominator is never $0$), then the limit holds?

Comment: This is nonsense. Probably you were given something in the statement of the problem that you left out here...

Comment: @DanielP Why do you conjecture that? That version is just as easily seen to be false

Comment: I don't yet see how the convergent version is false, but it may be. The only reason I conjectured that is because I couldn't immediately find a counterexample.

Comment: @DanielP Example isn't hard: $a_{2k}=1/k^2$, $a_{2k+1}=1/(2k^2)$.

Comment: I've calculated through with $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$, which is also convergent, and the answer was $\frac{1}{2}$, not $1$. So yeah, the statement is just false.

Answer (score 1):

As $\{a_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ is a decreasing sequence, we have that

$$a_{2j+1}\leq a_{2j} \quad \text{and} \quad a_{2j+1}\geq a_{2j+2}$$

for all $j\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and in particular then

$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{2j+1}\leq\sum_{j=1}^n a_{2j}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{j=1}^na_{2j+1}\geq\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}.$$

Finally, as $\{a_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ is decreasing and bounded below (by $0$), we have that it converges to some $a\in[0,\infty)$. Thus we can make the computation

$$0\leq\frac{\sum_{j=1}^na_{2j}}{\sum_{j=1}^na_{2j+1}}-1\leq\frac{\sum_{j=1}^na_{2j}}{\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}}-1=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^na_{2j}-\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}}{\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}}=\frac{a_2-a_{2(n+1)}}{\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}}.$$

Now as you yourself noted, we can make the computation

$$2\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}\geq\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}+\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j+1}=\sum_{j=4}^{2(n+1)+1}a_j\to\infty.$$

This implies that

$$\frac{a_2-a_{2(n+1)}}{\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}a_{2j}}\to0 \quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty,$$

(the numerator converges to $a_2-a$ and the denominator diverges to $\infty$) and so letting $n\to\infty$ in the estimate we did above, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^na_{2j}}{\sum_{j=1}^na_{2j+1}}=1$$

as desired.